# Custom Principal won't be propagated to EJB SessionContext on Jboss AS

Tags: jboss, ejb

In a EJB project, I need to replace the call princial name in "javax.ejb.SessionContext". I use Jboss AS 6.0 Final as the application server.

I defined a custom UserLoginModule that extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule and added a custom principal, but my custom principal won't be propagated to EJB SessionContext.

Here is some code from my custom login module:

```
@Override
protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {

    Group[] groups = new Group[2];
    groups[0] = new SimpleGroup("Roles");
    groups[0].addMember(createRoleIdentity());

    Group callerPrincipal = new SimpleGroup("CallerPrincipal");
    callerPrincipal.addMember(createIdentity(this.getUsername()));
    groups[1] = callerPrincipal;
    subject.getPrincipals().add(callerPrincipal);

    return groups;
}

@Override
protected Principal createIdentity(String username) throws LoginException {
    return new MyCustomPrincipal(username);
}

}
```

My custom login module works well, but the caller principal I get from "javax.ejb.SessionContext" is still SimplePrincipal.

It turned out that there is a Jobss bug: EJBContext.getCallerPrincipal() is not returning custom principal  https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8427

And a related topic: http://community.jboss.org/thread/44388.

I wonder if you have some experiences on this and is it safe to replace the default principal Jboss creates? Are ther any side effects?

Comment: This seems to be still a problem in JBoss 7

Answer (score 3):

With the help of my team, I got a solution, hope this can be helpful to those who have the same problem.

Instead of "sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()"
Use the following to get the custom principal:

```
        try {
            Subject subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");

            Set<Group> subjectGroups = subject.getPrincipals(Group.class);
            Iterator<Group> iter = subjectGroups.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Group group = iter.next();
                String name = group.getName();
                if (name.equals("CallerPrincipal")) {
                    Enumeration<? extends Principal> members = group.members();
                    if (members.hasMoreElements()) {

                               Principal principal = (Principal) members.nextElement();
                               return principal;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (PolicyContextException e1) {
            ...
        }
```