# Access caller roles in SLSB using Jboss7

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I'm using jboss as 7.1.1.Final and have configured a security-domain using LdapExtLoginModule. The login works so far.

I now want to access the roles loaded by the module in an SLSB. I know how to access the username. My example uses ejb 3.1 and prints the username to System.out.

I don't know how to access the roles and didn't find anything in the documentation. The EJBContext provides the method isCallerInRole(String) which proves that the context itself knows the roles but I can not find a method which returns a set of roles.

I know that I could write a custom LoginModule which extends the LdapExtLoginModule and sets a custom principal containing the roles. But maybe there is an easier approach using existing functionality. Does anybody know such approach?

SLSB code:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(IAService.class)
public class AService implements IAService
{

    @Resource
    private EJBContext context;

    @Override
    public void printUserData() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + context.getCallerPrincipal().getName());
        // TODO print roles
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody answered my question so far and because I finally have a working solution I will now share it with you:

The Java EE API does not provide any methods to access the information in server independent way. So I tried the method of writing a login module which sets a custom principal. [As it turns out this does not work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887182/custom-principal-wont-be-propagated-to-ejb-sessioncontext-on-jboss-as).

Inspired by the answer to this question I now use the following code to get the caller roles:

```
private Group getRoles() {
    final Subject subject = (Subject)PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
    final Set<Group> groups = subject.getPrincipals(Group.class);
    for (final Group group : groups) {
        if ("Roles".equals(group.getName())) {
            return group;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No roles group found");
}
```

The [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/acl/Group.html) returned by this method contains [Principals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) which have the names of the users groups. This only works on JBoss whose LoginModules set a Group of name "Roles".